# SQL How to find which customer has rented the most films?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling with a question that said Which customer has rented the
most films?

I am doing this using the Seikila sample database in MySQL. I have something that joins my tables together and attempts to give me a count but I know its wrong just looking at the actual data in the rental table. 
my code is as below

```
SELECT r.rental_id, cust.customer_id, count(*) as Total_Rentals
FROM rental as r
INNER JOIN customer AS cust on r.customer_id = cust.customer_id
GROUP BY cust.customer_id;
```

but it tells me for example customer 1 has rented 32 movies, which I know is wrong. what am I doing wrong?
since I was asked for clarification, the database I am using is:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/

And I am trying to find which customer has rented the most films, I am not entirely sure what my script is actually returning.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are argumenst to set functions.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The title says you want to count which customer has rented the most films, but your SQL statement is counting the number of times each customer has rented the same film. Which is it? They're not the same. Some sample data and the results you're looking to get from that data would help.

Comment: Brandon, can you show us what the result of the query is and what you would expect instead? There is quite some confusion about this question. You can solve it by adding even more details.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the column `rental_id` from the select list and sort the result by `count(*)` descending to return the top 1 row:

```
SELECT cust.customer_id, cust.name, count(*) as Total_Rentals
FROM rental as r
INNER JOIN customer AS cust on r.customer_id = cust.customer_id
GROUP BY cust.customer_id, cust.name
ORDER BY Total_Rentals DESC LIMIT 1
```

But if you only need the customer's id then there is no need for  a join:

```
SELECT customer_id, count(*) as Total_Rentals
FROM rental
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY Total_Rentals DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: So this is close, but customer ID it is returning isn't the one who rented the most films. the database I am using is from here by the way: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/

Comment: This code returns the customer with the most rental_ids. If your requirement is different then I guess you did not clarify it.

Comment: The most rental ids is not necessarily the most films

Answer (score 0):

You need to `join` `customer` and `rental`, `group by` `customer` id (without `rental` id) and count it:

```
SELECT cust.customer_id, count(*) as Total_Rentals
FROM rental as r
INNER JOIN customer AS cust on r.customer_id = cust.customer_id
GROUP BY cust.customer_id;
```

So this code should work. If it doesn't work, that probably means that you have duplicates or other nonconventional issues.

Comment: I would assume the question means distinct films, but I accept that it's ambiguous